Axios post call works but no other code is run, state not updated
The frontend has a function that handles a file upload and send the file to the backend to be processed. The backend then returns a json that should be used to update my React state. I set up a test call with axios.get() that works fine, where the backend passes in a string that is displayed on the webpage. console.log() also works fine in this test function. When it comes to my uploadDoc  function though, no console.log() s get run and state isn't updated. Here's my code:
App.js
const documentUploadHandler = ({files}) => {
    const [file] = files;
    uploadDoc(file);
  };

  const uploadDoc = async (document) => {
    console.log(doc_type)
    document.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('document', document);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });

      setDocType([response.data.classification]);
      console.log("hello")
      console.log(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading file:', error);
    }
  };

Server.py
@app.route('/api/upload', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def upload_file():
    global class_result
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            file = request.files['document']
            print(f"Uploading document {file.filename}")
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            class_result = classify_document("model5", file_path)
            return jsonify({"status": "get_success", "classification": class_result})

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Couldn't upload document: {e}")
            return jsonify({"status": "failed", "error": str(e)})
    return jsonify({"status": "post_success", "classification": class_result})

I've tried making the API call in Postman, which strangely only gives me the success status when I make a GET request, not a POST request. I'm not sure if this is relevant to the problem I'm having. I checked with dev tools in the Network tab, and it gives me status code 200 and it says that my request method is POST, so it seems to be using the right request type on the web.
I also tried updating the state in a separate function with axios.get() . This works in the sense that the new state is displayed, but only after I refresh the page. However, I need the state to be updated as soon as the backend has finished processing the file, which is why I'm trying to update state after my axios.post()  call.

files path is event.tatget.files maybe file is undefined

Please provide a [mre], you aren't showing how the documentUploadHandler function is called.

In short the axios.post create a promise not an actual value. The Promise is something that needs to be handled properly when the promise is fulfilled (since its an asynchronous call). Usually with .then((r)=>{setState(r)});
So for your case this should suffice:
axios.post('https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }).then((response)=>{
      setDocType([response.data.classification]);
      console.log("hello")
      console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error(err);
    });


Example component implementation, note the json parse, this only applies if they are actually json results:
export default function UploadFiles() {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState<File[]>([]);
    const filesRef = useRef(null);
    filesRef.current = files;
    const [backendAnswer, setBackendAnswer] = useState<any>();

    const handleFileSelect = useCallback((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.target.files.length === 0) setFiles([]);
        else setFiles([...event.target.files]);
    }, []);

    const uploadFiles = useCallback(() => {
        if (filesRef.current.length != 1) return;
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('document', filesRef.current[0]);

        axios.post('https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then((response) => { 
            if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Error in request at " + url);
            else return response.json();
        }).then((jsonParsedResponse)=>{
            console.log(jsonParsedResponse)
            setBackendAnswer(jsonParsedResponse);
        }).catch((error) => { console.error(error) });
    }, []);

    return <>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
            <label
                htmlFor="fileUpload"
            >
                Select files
                <input
                    id="fileUpload"
                    name="fileUpload"
                    type="file"
                    className="hidden"
                    onChange={handleFileSelect}
                />
            </label>
        </div>
        <button onClick={uploadFiles} >Upload</button>
    </>
}


I tried this and it still doesn't work. Nothing is getting logged to the console and state doesn't update. Even the console.log()s I have in the first line of the func aren't getting run.

@rainypuns, i had an await still in the example & removed it. Maybe take a look at this answer i wrote dealing with a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/78568521/19801189.

I removed await and async and the behavior is the same

The rest will be very much dependent on your implementation. I'm assuming the json() parse is missing because your backend has a jsonify written somewhere. The promises can be chained. I added a detailed example

Thanks so much for the help, you're right that it was an implementation issue. It ended up being a problem with how I was calling the uploadDoc function. I needed to specify that I was using a custom handler in order for the function to be called.

Awesome, glad i could help :)  If the problem is solved please add votes / answer so others know they don't need to look further :)
